# From a start date and an end date, how do I find what records are currently 'active'?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

My main database table has a Start Date and an End Date on rows to signify when a certain trial has started or ended.

So, if a trial has started and ended before the time period that is being queried, it is to be excluded.  If the trial has started and ended *after* the time period being queried, it should also be excluded.

However, if a trial either starts or ends in the time period, or starts before and finishes after the end of the time period, it should be included.

I've been scratching my head over this and I can't work it out.

This is my existing query which works, but seems to include trials that start and end *after* the time period being queried.

```
SELECT Count(Trials.Active) AS CountOfActiveTrials
FROM Trials
WHERE (((((Trials.DateStudyOpened)>[Forms]![Startup]![txtReportStartDate] And (Trials.DateStudyOpened)<[Forms]![Startup]![txtReportEndDate]) Or (Trials.DateStudyOpened)<[Forms]![Startup]![txtReportStartDate]) And Not (Trials.DateStudyOpened)>[Forms]![Startup]![txtReportEndDate]) AND (((Trials.DateStudyClosed)>[Forms]![Startup]![txtReportStartDate] And ((Trials.DateStudyClosed)<[Forms]![Startup]![txtReportEndDate]) Or (Trials.DateStudyClosed)>[Forms]![Startup]![txtReportEndDate]) Or (Trials.DateStudyClosed) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

This wound up being how to do it, it was as simple as this:

```
SELECT Count(Trials.Active) AS CountOfActiveTrials
FROM Trials
WHERE (((Trials.DateStudyOpened)<=[Forms]![Startup]![txtReportEndDate]) AND ((Trials.DateStudyClosed)>=[Forms]![Startup]![txtReportStartDate]));
```